# Servlet 3.0 annotations in conjuction with Guice

Tags: annotations, guice, servlet-filters, servlet-3.0, guice-servlet

I am attempting to update a legacy Guice application, and I was wondering if there is any sort of preferred way of doing things when taking Servlet 3.0 annotations into consideration.  For example, my application has a filter, FooFilter, which is defined in the Guice Module Factory method configureServlets(), as follows:

```
    Map<String, String> fooParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
    fooParams.put("someParam", "parameter information");                              
    filter("/foo.jsp","/foo/*").through(com.example.filter.FooFilter.class, fooParams);
```

Is the above binding still necessary, or will it interfere with the following using the @WebFilter Servlet 3.0 annotation:

```
    @Singleton
    @WebFilter(
        filterName="FooFilter",
        urlPatterns={"/foo.jsp", "/foo/*"},
        initParams = {
                    @WebInitParam(name="foo", value="Hello "),
                    @WebInitParam(name="bar", value=" World!")
                 })
    public class FooFilter implements Filter {
    etc....
```

Which method is now preferred? Will they mess with each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made quick draft how could a Servlet 3.0 support looks like. There could be a more elegant way to just call `filter(Filter Class with WebFilter annotation)` in `configureServlet` method, but that requires updated right to `guice-servlet` module, which is quite hard to distribute.

Well, what I did is a project at Github: https://github.com/xbaran/guice-servlet3

all you need to do is download and build. It is created on top of Guice 3.0 and works like this:

```
new Servlet3Module() {
      @Override
      protected void configureServlets3() {
        scanFilters(FooFilter.class.getPackage());
      }
};
```

The `Servlet3Module` extends `ServletModule` and contains a `scanFilters` method with `package` argument. This method will scan provided package from your classpath and try to register all classes with annotation `WebFilter` via `filter()` method.

This `scan` idea is based on `Sitebricks` (guice web framework created by [Dhanji R. Prasanna](https://twitter.com/dhanji)) configuration system.

Honestly, I just make a draft, never try if it works. But hopefully it will. If you have any problem or question, just let me know.

PS: The support for servlets, listeners and so on could be added to, if you wish.

Comment: Milan, have you used this in production or testing?  Are there any hiccups after the scanning is complete?

Comment: I just checked out the code, and it answers my question indirectly in that the servlets  and filters must still be registered through Guice.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Guice do not support Servlet 3.0 annotations directly yet. So, this is kind of workaround, but it does what you need. As you said, I just using Guice API to register filters so, there should be no problem to use it in production.

Comment: Milan, don't you think this way of doing can interfer with a true Servlet 3.0 container. This solution will work with servlet container < 3.0 . I mean servlet 3.0 container will also try to register the servlet with their own scan mechanism. I think in that case we have to plug to API/SPI of JEE . What do you think ?

Comment: taharqa question makes much sense.